# Add new column to DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I have a class

```
[Table("Member")]
public class Member
{
   [Key]
   public int id;
   public string name;
}
```

and this class is defined as a table in DB. Now I would like to add a new one with primary and foreign key as follows using nuget but I don't know how.

```
public class Work
{
   public int id;
   public int memberId;
}
```

**Update** In the Console, I have tried adding a new class `Add_migration AddWork` but it doesn't create me a new table only a xxx_AddWork.cs with empty `Up` and `Down` methods.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'd like to generate a new column in the existing DB from the console commandline

Comment: O_o ... you're probably referring to some sort of ORM library that you retrieved with nuget. Check your nuget console/manager and see what you installed so you can revise your question.

Comment: Yes, I am using EF, nothing different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add a column to the database by from the console. You have to do that through the class itself:

```
public class Work
{
   [Key]
   public int id; {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("Member")]
   public int memberId {get; set;}

   public virtual Member Member {get; set;}
}
```